# User indicator Configuration

Tags: unity, indicator

In user-indicators one user could see all other user names

I want to hide all names from Unity indicator panel

for security reasons I don't want users to see other user names

Answer (score 2):

Fisrt, Install Ubuntu-tweak if you don't have yet

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

**Using Version 0.7.3**

Then go to **Tweaks** menu and choose **Session Indicator** and then under **User Indicator** you can Turn it Off

[image]

**Using Ubuntu Tweak Version 0.6.2:**

Then go to **Tweaks** menu and choose **Session Control** and then under **User Menu Options** you can uncheck **Show user menu**

[image]

Comment: Ok am sry the version i have is (0.6.2) Feel free to change the option names according to the last version u've gotten