# How can I hide the switch user part of Unity's top panel session indicator?

Tags: unity, indicator

In Ubuntu 13.10's Unity Panel (the top panel, not the launcher), the **session indicator** (top right corner) shows the names of previously logged in users.

This allows switching users, but for privacy reasons I would like to be able to *hide those user names*, as a lot of people use machines in our computer pool. It seems that in older versions of Unity there was a dedicated 'user-indicator' in the panel for that purpose, which could be configured via dconf.

Here are some of several pages that I've found on which is explained how to show/hide things in the old user indicator as well as the session indicator:

- [User indicator Configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195180/user-indicator-configuration)
- [Do not display user name in the panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87649/do-not-display-user-name-in-the-panel)

Related dconf keys, that were referred to in different posts, are:

- `apps > indicator-session > user-show-menu`
- `com > canonical > indicator > session > user-show-menu`

Unfortunately, all these keys don't exist anymore. The user indicator seems to have been merged into the session indicator. The graphical tool Ubuntu Tweak doesn't have the config settings any more either.

Is there any way to hide the switch user part of the session indicator? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What I have used in the past is the following from this link: [How to easily hide the username in the Unity panel](http://iloveubuntu.net/how-easily-hide-username-unity-panel)

Steps:

1. Install dconf-editor: `apt-get install dconf-tools`
2. Open it and navigate to `apps-->indicator-session` and on the right-side, uncheck `show-real-name-on-panel`
3. Reboot

Additionally, you can open a terminal and type the following:

`gesettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user show-menu false`

Or download and install Ubuntu Tweak from here: http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ and follow these steps to turn off Fast User Switching which will hide the list of other users:

1. Click on Tweaks
2. Click on Miscellaneous
3. Check the box next to `Disable "Fast User Switching"`

Comment: The problem is not to hide the name of the user who is currently logged in. The indicator-session thing shows (in our case _many_) usernames of other people that have accounts there. This may be useful for fast switching to another user (which is not necessary in our case), but for privacy reasons we would like to hide _those_ names. That a user can see his own username in the panel is not so bad, and it can be turned off the way you describe. I just wasn't able to figure out how to hide the other names, as all information on how to do that seems to be outdated.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the above solution and two additional for you. I've tested the answer on Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, 13.04 and 13.10 and it accomplished what you are after. Hope this helps!

Comment: I found the option you described in Ubuntu Tweak 0.8.6. I've just tried it. As far as I can tell it has no effect on _indicator-session_ on our systems.
After the checkbox was set, it remained set when I relaunched Tweak. Starting a new session or `unity --replace`, or even a reboot doesn't change that. No matter wether I set this option as normal user or as root, it remains set, but has no effect. Obviously, Tweak does save it somehow (maybe in dconf), but on our systems it's not disabling the list of user names.
But in any case, thanks for your effort.

Comment: Very strange! Have you tried typing `gesettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user show-menu false` in the console yet?

Comment: In dconf, under `com.canonical.indicator...`, there are no keys `session`, `session-user`, `session.user` etc. That's why I wrote in my question that the old keys to configure the indicator are gone. All that gsettings does is write to the dconf database. But it seems to me that the indicator doesn't care about those keys anymore. That's the problem.